# Does Unity MVC resolve types by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm new to DI scenarios and I'm implementing a DI scenario using Unity and asp.net mvc.

I was trying to inject a `DbContex` instance into my `UnitOfWork` class. I registered the instance but I noticed that `DbContex`object had been already injected without writing the code for resolving the `DbContex`.

How it could be possible? Does Unity resolving the instances by default?

I thought it was my responsibility to write this "resolving code" for the DI to work.

For instance, when I'm injecting dependencies into Controllers I must write a code like this in GetControllerInstance method:

`return MvcUnityContainer.Container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only resolve the root object, e.g., the controller class. Unity would then look at the constructor of this class and will see that it has some dependencies (constructor parameters). It will then automatically try to resolve these dependencies. If these dependencies have dependencies themselves, it will resolve these first...

This process is called auto-wiring. Without auto-wiring, why would anyone use a DI container? ([Not that I think that you should use one in the first place](http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/08/23/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex-object-graphs/))

Answer (score 0):

Unity by default "registers" all concrete types loaded in the process - so you can call `.Resolve` with concrete type and get result (assuming constructor of that type actually can get called by Unity).

For interfaces you need to register mapping to concrete type/instances so.

Comment: You said Unity by default "registers" but I need to know whether Unity by default "resolves" all types that have been registered.